# JPA Transaction - CrudRepository #save(List) not rolled back

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.9 with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and Camel 2.20.1. 
As input I get an XML file with a sequence of elements, which I unmarshal with JAXB and after that I aggregate them to a list of elements.

For that I defined a **Element class** where I associate a root element for JAXB and annotated it as a JPA entity.

```
@Entity
@Table (name="tblElement", schema="comp")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Element implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column (name="name")
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String name;

    public void Element(){}

    //getter and setter methods
    ...
}
```

So my camel route processes a list of entries which I want to store to a MySQL database (version: 5.1.73).

```
@Component
public class CompRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private ElementDao elementDao;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        DataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat("com.comp.beans");

        from(file:src/test/resources/input)
                .convertBodyTo(byte[].class, "UTF-8")
                .split().tokenizeXML("element") 
                .unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat) 
                .setProperty("SplitSize", simple("${header.CamelSplitSize}"))

                .aggregate(constant(true), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy()) 
                    .completionSize(simple("${property.SplitSize}"))

                .bean(elementDao, "insertElementList");
    }
}
```

I'm not so familiar with JPA and the transaction manager, so I configured it according these documentations:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://compserver:3306/comp
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**JpaConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = CompApplication.class)
class JpaConfig {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        String entities = ClassUtils.getPackageName(CompApplication.class);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(entities);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier (value = "jpaTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

**CompApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CompApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(CompApplication.class);
          app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
          app.run(args);
  }
```

}

**ElementDao.java**

```
@Service
public class ElementDao {
    @Autowired
    ElementRepository elementRepository;

    @Transactional (transactionManager = "jpaTransactionManager", readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void insertElementList(Exchange exchange) {
        if(exchange.getIn().getBody() instanceof List) {
             List<Element> elements= convertListToElementList(exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class));
             if (elements != null) {
                 elementRepository.save(elements);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**ElementRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface ElementRepository extends CrudRepository<Element, Long> {

}
```

But my transaction configuration is not working correct. Because if an error occured e.g. while storing the 5th element, the whole transaction  is not rolled back. It should not insert any elements. But still the first 4 elements are stored and commited.

I don't understand this behavor? How can I set my service #insertElementList transactional that the whole operation is rolled back when an exception occured during database storage?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
     <groupId>com.company</groupId>
     <artifactId>company</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1</version>
     <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
     </parent> 
     <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       <camel.version>2.20.1</camel.version>
     </properties>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
             <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
             <version>${camel.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
             <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
             <version>${camel.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>mysql</groupId>
             <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
             <version>5.1.45</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
             <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
             <version>2.20.0</version>
         </dependency>    
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
         </dependency>   
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
             <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
             <version>${camel.version}</version>
         </dependency>   
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
             <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
             <version>9.0.0.1</version>
         </dependency>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
             <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
             <version>4.8</version>
         </dependency>    
         <dependency>
             <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
             <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
             <version>1.1.8</version>
         </dependency>     
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>  
         <dependency>
             <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
             <version>2.5</version>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>
 </project>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 4th record? you seem to be storing all at once ..elementRepository.save(elements);

Comment: I tested it e.g. with a list of 10 elements, but the 5th element will cause an PersistenceException. So I would expect that no records are saved. But in my case nevertheless the first 4 elements are stored. I don't understand why it is not completely rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was the database and not my configuration. The MySql table was of type MyISAM, which does not support transactions and roll back. So I converted the table to InnoDB and now it works - when the transaction fails, all is rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring documentation.

@Transactional on beans in the same application context it is defined in. This means that, if you put annotation in a WebApplicationContext for a DispatcherServlet, it only checks for @Transactional beans in your controllers, and not your services.

So, your save method is not transactional , include that package also in which
save method is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm sorry, I don't understand the solution. Where should I include which package?